# Anyway to set a text filter default value to the current user?

Tags: list

thanks for any help you may have - first time poster, long time SP n00b.

**Situation:**

I have a SharePoint 2010 list with a lot of data. At the top I have a few filters that the user can manipulate to get the data that is relevant to them. I'm currently trying to figure out a way that when the user opens the list, the default for "Staff Name" is automatically the set to the current user who is browsing the list.

[image: "Staff Name" would have a default value of the name of the current user]

As such, does anyone know if it's possible to use formulas in the default value section here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `Staff Name` is a `People Picker` Field, try to use `Current User Filter` 
 web part instead to can filter by the `Current User`,

[image]

**Another option,** you can modify your View and filter by `[ME]` function.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! For anyone who needs help setting up the Current User Filter - this video was a great help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sl4tnqV_g5U